# Correct way to reference css in servlet with JSP called by another page

Tags: css, jsp, servlets, include

I have a Java WebServlet (e.g. javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet @WebServlet) app that returns a JSP page as a response to a POST request. It is essentially a "widget" for a dashboard.

All works as expected when I make the post call directly to the service, including resources such as .css includes

However, when I make an ajax call to the service from a web page (to populate a div)

```
$.ajax( "http://localhost:8680/jsdv-status-panel/tsv-multi",
        { data: JSON.stringify(
              {"some json here" }
          ),
          contentType: 'application/json',
          type: 'POST',
          success:  function(data){
              $("#main_div").html(data);
            }
        });
```

the browser gives an error

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:63342/test_app/resources/css/statuspanel.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet
```

which I understand is indicative of it not being able to locate the resource, which I understand, because the .css file in the JSP is using a relative URI of {context}/resources/css/statuspanel.css

So, the web page making the call to get the JSP is transposing the {context} to it's own context I assume.

This is "fixable" by specifying the complete URL to the service path of the css resource such as

```
http://localhost:8680/my_web_service/restful_path/resources/css/statuspanel.css
```

My question is - is this the correct, or preferred method of doing this ? 
Just making sure the resource is accessible from the client and specifying the complete URL and NOT using a relative path for the resource ?

Or do I maybe have something configured improperly ?

I don't "think" I have a problem or need for mapping a context resource type in web.xml, and I don't "think" I need anything like

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

because it finds the resource on the server-side (which means the DefaultDispatcher is finding it locally ok yes ?).

Servlet

```
@WebServlet(name="jsdv-status-panel", asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = { "/tsv-last-value", "/tsv-window", "/tsv-multi" }, loadOnStartup = 1)
```

This does NOT work on the client-side

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/css/statuspanel.css"/>
```

This DOES work on the client-side

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8680/jsdv-status-panel/resources/css/statuspanel.css"/>
```

So - I am just guessing that {context} is the reason, and .css is always client-side ? so specify URL/URI explicitly in the JSP (or whatever is server-side)

Yes ?

I have no web.xml overrides- just the @WebServlet annotations.